ogr2ogr gives an overflow error
I'm trying to use ogr2ogr to import shapefile data in my PostgreSQL database.
The MAC command line I use for this is export PGPASSWORD=xxx* ogr2ogr -skipfailures -nln xx_table -f PostgreSQL PG:"host=localhost port=5432 dbname=xx_dbname user=postgres" 'Documents/MSOA_2021_EW_BSC_V2.shp' -lco precision=NO
Unfortunately I get this error:

ERROR 1: INSERT command for new feature failed. ERROR:  numeric field
overflow DETAIL:  A field with precision 12, scale 11 must round to an
absolute value less than 10^1.

This is odd as the settings for my PostgreSQL table and my .SHP Layer are the same?
.shp file in QGIS:

PostgreSQL Table:

What is wrong?

I believe a scale of 12 and precision of 11 means that you can't have more than one digit before the decimal.  So a value 1.232323 is acceptable, but 15.98765 isn't.  The error might be suggesting that values in your shapefile already exceed that limitation.

The option -lco precision=NO should prevent that issue. Do you perhaps have an old table from previous failures at the bottom? Try with -overwrite.

Please tell what happened with -overwrite.

You should run the command with:
-lco PRECISION=NO

Which it looks like you are doing.
You can try:
-lco OVERWRITE=YES -overwrite

Table is probably already be there, as you have run the command with -skipfailures. Although you probably also got a message saying layer creation options are being skipped.
